# How to access special character like $,# using jq

Tags: shell, sh, jq

I am trying to process some string which has special characters in it like `abc123#45` or `ab$123` or `qwe&123`.

I am trying to fetch it in shell like:

In json file : `foo=qwe$123`

```
foo=`cat tmp_json | jq -r  '.keys.foo'`
```

But it is coming like :

```
foo=qwe23
```

JSON input

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "name": "xyz",
    "version": 7,
    "lastUpdated": 1585551422521
  },
  "keys": {
    "abc": "qwe$123",
    "foo": "qwe$123"
  }
}
```

Comment: Include an example json file in your question.

Comment: Json file contents: {"metadata":{"name":"xyz","version":7,"lastUpdated":1585551422521},"keys":{"abc": "qwe$123","foo":"qwe$123"}}

Comment: **In** your question (And properly formatted), not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

When shell strings contain special characters that you do not want to be interpreted specially by the shell, you have to quote them using single quotes, e.g. `foo='qwe$123'`

Using bash 4.x, the form

```
x=`...`
```

does not present any problems with respect to characters such `$`, `#`, or `&`, though it should be noted that the preferred form for such assignments is `x=$(...)`

However these forms should only be used with great care because of other special characters.

Generally, it would be better to use an idiom such as:

```
jq -r .... | while -r read line ; do .... ; done
```

Depending on your requirements, you might also wish to consider jq's `@sh` filter.